# Property 'dateComponentFramework' does not exist on type 'GridOptions

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to use some code in Angular 13 when using AG Grid Version 27.2.1 and i am trying to assign some Date Option to my grid.In AG Gris 25.01 this was stll an option under GridOptions. What hs this been replaced by and how do i get this to work in 27.x again ?

```
import {Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid-community';

import {DateComponent} from '../date-component/date.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from '../header-component/header.component';
import {ApiService} from '../../../../services/api/api.service';
import {takeWhile} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rich-grid',
    templateUrl: 'rich-grid.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['rich-grid.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class RichGridComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    public showGrid: boolean;
    public rowData: any[];
    public rowCount: string;
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() columnDefs: any[];
    @Input() rowSelection = 'multiple';
    @Input() rowModelType = 'infinite';
    @Input() paginationPageSize = 100;
    @Input() cacheOverflowSize = 2;
    @Input() maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests = 2;
    @Input() infiniteInitialRowCount = 1;
    @Input() maxBlocksInCache = 2;
    @Input() getRowNodeId: Function;
    @Input() dataUrl: string;

    private alive = true;

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {
        // we pass an empty gridOptions in, so we can grab the api out
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.showGrid = true;
        this.gridOptions.dateComponentFramework = DateComponent;
        this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = {
            resizable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filter: true,
            headerComponentFramework: <new() => HeaderComponent>HeaderComponent,
            headerComponentParams: {
                menuIcon: 'fa-bars'
            }
        };
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be registered in **components** grid property

```
components: {
    agDateInput: DateComponent,
}
```

Check this link: [Ag-grid Date component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-date)